# Manipulating final score calculated by functions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to manipulate final score that calculated by functions.

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "functions": [
                {
                    //Some decay function --> f1
                },
                {
                    //Some decay function --> f2
                },
                {
                    //Some field_value_factor --> f3
                }                   
            ],
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost_mode": "replace"
        }
    }
}
```

This query calculates final score like this: `final score = f1 + f2 + f3`

Is there a way to make a final touch to score like this?

`final score = (f1 + f2 + f3) * doc['fancy_field']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `function_score` query within another one having a [`script_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score) function that would multiply the `_score` of the wrapped query (i.e. f1+f2+f3) by `doc.fancy_field.value`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "functions": [
                {
                    //Some decay function --> f1
                },
                {
                    //Some decay function --> f2
                },
                {
                    //Some field_value_factor --> f3
                }                   
            ],
            "score_mode": "sum",
            "boost_mode": "replace"
          }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "_score * doc['fancy_field'].value"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```